# How to find the exact time left

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am working on the reminder app and I have taken two properties one is the date which is in Datetime format and another is time which is of type string .My problem is I am not able to get the exact hours and min and sec when the user set the reminder for the future date how to subtract he future time with the current time so that I can get exact hours and min and sec left. Please help me out

thank you
Here is my model class

```
 private DateTime _date=DateTime.Today.Date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
                TimeSpan tp = value - DateTime.Now;
                if (tp.TotalDays>0)
                {
                    RemainingDays = (int)tp.TotalDays;
                    //TimeSpan ts = value- System.TimeSpan.FromHours(Time);
                    //string.Format("{0}:{1}", System.Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours).ToString(), ts.Minutes.ToString());

                    RemainingHours = (int)tp.TotalHours;

                    RemainingMin = (int)tp.Minutes;
                    RemainingSec = (int)tp.Seconds;
                    SetProperty(ref _date, value);
                }

        }

    }

    private string _time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
    public string Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set
        { SetProperty(ref _time, value); }
    }

    private int _remainingdays;
    public int RemainingDays
    {
        get { return _remainingdays; }
        set
        {

            SetProperty(ref _remainingdays, value);
        }

    }

    private int _remaininghours;
    public int RemainingHours
    {
        get { return _remaininghours; }
        set
        {

            SetProperty(ref _remaininghours, value);
        }

    }

    private int _remainingmin;
    public int RemainingMin
    {
        get { return _remainingmin; }
        set
        {

            SetProperty(ref _remainingmin, value);
        }

    }

    private int _remainingsec;
    public int RemainingSec
    {
        get { return _remainingsec; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _remainingsec, value);
        }
    }

  }
```

}
This is my UI were i have to show the time left

```
  <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

                                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkRemaningTime" FontSize="50"  >
                                <Run Text="{Binding RemainingHours}"/>
                                <Run Text=":"/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding RemainingMin}"/>
                                <Run Text=":"/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding RemainingSec}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: 'Date' is not a good property name. Also SetProperty() appears to be a method whose sole task is set private vars. Why?. Aside from that, I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: so now you've edited and removed SetProperty(). was it not required in the first instance?

Comment: yes sir it is required basically to notify I have created another class where INotifyPropertyChanged interface is implemented so this class help me whenever if  I have to notify the properties in the model class I use the  SetProperty method .

Comment: Not an answer but...appointments are thought of as a time of day in reference to the prevailing time zone and daylight saving rules in effect at the time and place where the appointment is or that used by the appointment scheduler. The DateTimeOffset type comes close to meeting such requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a step back.  You are using a property setter in a very untraditional way.  Consider the client who writes this code:

```
var y = new YourObject();
Console.WriteLine(y.Date); // prints today's date
y.Date = new DateTime(2015,1,1);
Console.WriteLine(y.Date); // still prints today's date  (?!)
```

Setting `y.Date` didn't change `y.Date` at all!  It mutated several other fields/properties.  This violates the core [property design principle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that properties "should be seen as smart fields", not to mention the [Principle of Least Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Moreover, instead of getting back a `TimeSpan` -- a well-documented type for describing the interval between two dates -- you are forcing the client to use your own, limited, methods to get the same data.

Instead, consider:

```
class YourObject
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public TimeSpan TimeUntilDate
    {
        get {return Date - DateTime.Now;}
    }
}
```

And let the client use the resultant `TimeSpan` as necessary.